# Php Array accessing

Tags: php

I am trying to access an item from the array, the issue is with the line:

```
src=$videoArray[0]
```

I have tried a few ways but none seem to work.

```
<?php
$videoArray = array(
"//www.youtube.com/embed/nEBHkEeH42Y",
"//www.youtube.com/embed/1GlticqrECU",
"//www.youtube.com/embed/BMOUsI8JIaI",
);
?>



<iframe width="520" height="280" src=$videoArray[0] frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: make it src="<?php echo $videoArray[0]; ?>" You can't access PHP variables from HTML like that.

Answer (score 3):

You need `<?php ?>` tags for the array to echo out, and you are missing the quotes around the src attribute.

```
<iframe width="520" height="280" src="<?php echo $videoArray[0]; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your PHP tags and echo statement:

```
<iframe width="520" height="280" src="<?php echo $videoArray[0]; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

or shorthand syntax:

```
<iframe width="520" height="280" src="<?= $videoArray[0]; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: do not use short tags

Comment: @keaner the right comment is,  "don't use short tags if of you plan to distribute your software and support php versions prior to 5.4".

Comment: no John, Dont use short tags, ever. Future-proof :)

Comment: That thinking is obsolete. Short tags for echoing (`<?=`) is always enabled as of php 5.4. It *is* the future.

Comment: "PHP also allows for short open tags <? and ?> (which are discouraged because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option. "

I agree with the echo part, but as a general practice you should not use short tags.

Comment: Did you even read what you wrote? Do you see `<?=` in there? Do you know why not? Because `<?=` is a *[permenant part of PHP now](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)*. Why? Because it's darn useful. So, once again, unless you plan to distribute the software and support PHP 5.3 an older (all of which are deprecated by the way) short tags are good and encouraged. So, once again, your advice is obsolete and not accurate. It's important that you stay up to date with this kind of information.

Comment: And it should be said that regular shot tags `<?` should not be used anywhere. They serve no purpose and only create other problems.

Comment: agree to disagree I guess. I refuse to use short codes like <? ?> . while <?= is fine technically, it does not help other, older coders, who will have been taught from day one not to use short tags. so I will not use it yet. To each their own

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="520" height="280" src="<?php $videoArray[0] ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need reusable code...

```
<?php
$videoArray = array(
    "//www.youtube.com/embed/nEBHkEeH42Y",
    "//www.youtube.com/embed/1GlticqrECU",
    "//www.youtube.com/embed/BMOUsI8JIaI",
);

foreach($videoArray as $videoLink) {
    ?>
    <iframe width="520" height="280" src="<?php echo $videoLink; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php
}
?>
```